# React Fetch for a Node program

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

I have a fetch on React client program which is as below:

```
checkStatus(response) {
    if (response.status >= 200 && response.status < 300) {
      return response
    } else {
      var error = new Error(response.statusText)
      error.response = response
      throw error
    }
};

componentDidMount() {
  console.log('in the did mount ' +this.state);
  return fetch('/addUser', {
    method: 'put',
    body: JSON.stringify(this.state),
    headers: {
      'Accept': 'application/json',
      'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    }
  })
    .then(this.checkStatus)
    .then(()=>console.log('updated!!!'))
};
```

This is **App.jsx**.

In the Node End of the project I have `addUser.js` under `routers` folder, which has the code below:

```
let router = require('express').Router(); let bodyParser =
   require('body-parser');

   // parse application/json router.use(bodyParser.json());

   router.put('/addUser', update);

   function update(req, res) {   console.log('updating-', req.body);  
   res.sendStatus(200); }
```

The client page is returning:

> resource not found: http://localhost:3000/addUser

Is there any config that I am  missing in the above.

I have this on a react node project.

Comment: When you open http://localhost:3000/addUser do you see anything?

Comment: I see the first page from which I am calling componentdidmount function to call the node program.

Comment: At what URL is your server deployed at?

Comment: http://localhost:3100

Comment: Add CORS to your express (see here: https://github.com/expressjs/cors ) and change your App.jsx to `return fetch('http://localhost:3100/addUser', {`

Comment: This Chrome plugin is handy for enabling CORS locally https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/allow-control-allow-origi/nlfbmbojpeacfghkpbjhddihlkkiljbi?hl=en

Comment: After adding the above updates I am getting: Failed to load resource: Could not connect to the server. But when I do http://localhost/3100 I get Welcome message from the server

Comment: actually this is the error that i am getting:Failed to load resource: Origin http://localhost:3000 is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.

Comment: This is a CORS error. You should try doing what @acdcjunior suggested.

Comment: I did the steps which were suggested and thats when I got the error:Origin localhost:3000 is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.